# rails ajax get calls wrong action until after page refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, button, refresh

As shown, 'import' is the action in the controller. This loads a data grid housed in _list.html.erb and then reinserts _list into _index.html.erb. Sort buttons (ajax) are in the top row of the grid, also reinserting _list within _index. The sort buttons work fine, but only AFTER a page refresh. When used immediately after load, the buttons call the 'show' action with 'id=import'. Moving the button $get call to _list.html.erb does not work.

I came across some little know jQuery/Ajax trickery that more explicitly assigns method/action to the call. Not that it's a sure fix, but worth a try, if only i could find it again) Any ideas...at all?

_index.html.erb...

```
<%= form_tag import_mtab1lets_path, :method => 'post', :id => "import_mtab1lets" do %>
```

submit is caught and ajax used...

```
$.post("/mtab1lets/import", $("#import_mtab1lets").serialize(), null, 'script');
return false;
```

sort button action...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tablets th a, #tablets .pagination a").on("click", function() {
  $.get("/mtab1lets/list", null, null, "script");
  return false;
  });
});
```

in routes, i've ordered things this way...

```
match "/mtab1lets/show/:id" => "mtab1lets#show", via: 'get'
match "/mtab1lets/list" => "mtab1lets#list", via: 'get'  

resources :mtab1lets do
  collection { post :import }
end

match "/mtab1lets/:id" => "mtab1lets#update", via: 'post'

resources :mtab1lets
```

Answer (score 0):

I can answer it, myself. _index is the parent page for _list. The bind for the sort buttons are in _index, NOT _list. So, when _list is reloaded by ajax, the bind in _index is not called. And it needs to be) I extended the ajax call, repeating the bind in .done. This little stumper has been answered in like fashion all over the place.

```
$.post( "/mtab1lets/import", $("#import_mtab1lets").serialize(), null, 'script', function() {
})
.done(function() {
    $("#tablets th a, #tablets .pagination a").on("click", function() {
        $.get("/mtab1lets/list", null, null, "script");
        return false;
    });
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "ajax load error" );
});
```